# text of button do not show in last row of datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a `DataGridView` with `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn cb = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
cb.Name = columnName;
cb.HeaderText = headerText;
cb.Text = buttonCaption;
cb.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
cb.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
this.Columns.Add(cb);
```

[image: Picture]

Why did it not show the text of the button at the last row?

Comment: is it supposed to be the same text on each button in each column?

Comment: the final row in DataGridView by default is an unassigned, editable line. If you havent disabled this, then there will be no values in the cells